# How to use apollo graphql (react) in a js function in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, react-apollo

This is how my simple function to synchronize the data looks like:

**Function**

```
import { getData } from './api/index'

export default async function synchronize (navigator) {
  const data = await getData()
  // ... then store data to local db...
}
```

I'm fetching some data from the server using an RESTful API:

**getData**

```
import { Alert, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

async function getData () {
  try {
    const lastSynched = await AsyncStorage.getItem('data.lastSynched')
    const date = lastSynched ? Number(Date.parse(lastSynched)) / 1000 : 0
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth.token')
    const uriBase = 'http://localhost:3000'

    let response = await fetch(`${uriBase}/get-data/${date}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-access-token': token
      }
    })
    let responseJson = await response.json()
    return responseJson
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert('Error', 'Could not synchronize data')
  }
}

export default getData
```

But now I'm using apollo graphQL and I do not understand how to get the data using a query as I'm using here a function (synchronize()) - not a component.

Comment: Here you are not using apollo. You are trying to execute request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think good start will be from this [link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html). Here you have good examples how to use Apollo client to execute query and fetch data.

Maybe I don't understand properly what is issue but here is high level of Apollo usage.

First you will need to create Apollo client and supply at least URI to GraphQL endpoint.

```
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://w5xlvm3vzz.lp.gql.zone/graphql"
});
```

Once you created client you should than execute your query with previously created client like in following:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

client
  .query({
    query: gql`
      {
        rates(currency: "USD") {
          currency
        }
      }
    `
  })
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Make sure that you installed `apollo-boost react-apollo graphql-tag graphql` packages. Also make sure that you wrap your query into GraphQL tag like this because it will compile your query.